# How to get a random number in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, random

How do I generate a random number between `0` and `n`?

Comment: Using `srand <some_number>` before writing `rand` code will give you a deterministic (i.e. repeatable) pseudo-random sequence, if you need that.  https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.6/Random.html#method-c-srand

Answer (score 994, accepted):

Use [`rand(range)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand)

From [Ruby Random Numbers](http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2007/3/25/Ruby-random-numbers/1042):

> If you needed a random integer to simulate a roll of a six-sided die, you'd use: `1 + rand(6)`. A roll in craps could be simulated with `2 + rand(6) + rand(6)`.
>
> Finally, if you just need a random float, just call `rand` with no arguments.

---

As [Marc-André Lafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279/marc-andre-lafortune) mentions in [his answer below (go upvote it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby/2773866#2773866), [Ruby 1.9.2 has its own `Random` class](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2009/07/20/ruby-1-9-2-preview-1-released/) (that Marc-André himself [helped to debug](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3104), hence the [1.9.2 target](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/versions/show/11) for that feature).

For instance, in this [game where you need to guess 10 numbers](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35817496/random-integer-within-a-r.aspx), you can initialize them with:

```
10.times.map{ 20 + Random.rand(11) } 
#=> [26, 26, 22, 20, 30, 26, 23, 23, 25, 22]
```

Note:

- Using `Random.new.rand(20..30)` (using `Random.new`) generally would not be a good idea, as explained in detail (again) by [Marc-André Lafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279/marc-andre-lafortune), in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby/2773866#2773866) (again).
- But if you don't use `Random.new`, then the [class method `rand`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Random.src/M000693.html) only takes a `max` value, not a `Range`, as [banister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66725/banister) (energetically) points out in the comment (and as documented in the [docs for `Random`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Random.html)).  Only the [instance method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Random.src/M000688.html) can take a `Range`, as illustrated by [generate a random number with 7 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722881/generate-a-random-number-with-7-digits/5723105#5723105).

This is why the equivalent of `Random.new.rand(20..30)` would be `20 + Random.rand(11)`, since `Random.rand(int)` returns “a random integer greater than or equal to zero and *less than the argument*.” `20..30` includes 30, I need to come up with a random number between 0 and 11, excluding 11.

Comment: Isn't this terribly non-ruby-like? I thought everything is an object, least-surprise and that...

Comment: @yar: It is a bit "perlish". Now Ruby has it's Random class (see my answer)

Comment: `Random.rand` does not accept a range, and so this code does not work: `Random.rand(20..30)`, I am running on 1.9.2p180.

Comment: also the top-level `rand` method does not accept a range! how the heck did you get 74 points when your code is totally broken?!

Comment: @banister: that is strange, according to the current implementation, it (i.e: `Random.rand`) should support Range: http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-19/repository/entry/random.c#L1124

Comment: @VonC, im pretty sure that's the docs for the Random#rand _instance\_method_ you're looking at there ;). For some reason the Random.rand class method behaves differently to the Random#rand instance method in this case

Comment: @banister: very good point (that '`static`' there through me off). I have edited the answer to reflect your remark. To answer your other question "how the heck did you get 74 points when your code is totally broken?!", it is because up until less than a month ago, this answer contained "`Random.new.rand(20..30)`, ie *instance* method `rand` ;) The recent edit in [Marc-André's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby/2773866#2773866) prompted me to update (a bit too quickly) that code in order to use the class method.

Comment: @VonC ah :) sorry if i was a bit harsh, it just surprised me

Comment: `Random.rand` *does* accept a range, actually. (Since 1.9.3, I believe.)

Comment: Link to game guessing 10 numbers is gone.

Comment: @DanRosenstark: 8 years later... `method(:rand)` outputs `#<Method: Object(Kernel)#rand>`. So `rand` is a `Kernel` method, available to every `Object`. You can call `self.send(:rand, 0..10)` if it makes you feel better.

Answer (score 612):

While you can use `rand(42-10) + 10` to get a random number between `10` and `42` (where 10 is inclusive and 42 exclusive), there's a better way since Ruby 1.9.3, where you are able to call:

```
rand(10...42) # => 13
```

Available for all versions of Ruby by requiring my [`backports`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem.

Ruby 1.9.2 also introduced the `Random` class so you can create your own random number generator objects and has a nice API:

```
r = Random.new
r.rand(10...42) # => 22
r.bytes(3) # => "rnd"
```

The `Random` class itself acts as a random generator, so you call directly:

```
Random.rand(10...42) # => same as rand(10...42)
```

***Notes on `Random.new`***

In most cases, the simplest is to use `rand` or `Random.rand`. Creating a new random generator each time you want a random number is a *really bad idea*. If you do this, you will get the random properties of the initial seeding algorithm which are atrocious compared to the properties of the [random generator itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister).

If you use `Random.new`, you should thus call it *as rarely as possible*, for example once as `MyApp::Random = Random.new` and use it everywhere else.

The cases where `Random.new` is helpful are the following:

- you are writing a gem and don't want to interfere with the sequence of `rand`/`Random.rand` that the main programs might be relying on
- you want separate reproducible sequences of random numbers (say one per thread)
- you want to be able to save and resume a reproducible sequence of random numbers (easy as `Random` objects can marshalled)

Comment: Excellent! +1. I have completed my own answer to reflect that new feature (and mentioning your contribution with Bug #3104 ;) ).

Comment: @yar: My `backports` gem is simply a collection of methods that are new to RUby 1.8.7, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, but implemented in Ruby. I use RubySpec to insure that the results are compatible with Ruby.

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune, thanks for that. It's always been strange to me how much of Ruby is implemented in non-Ruby (C or whatever) due to speed requirements. But them's the breaks

Comment: @yar: Until there is a really good implementation of Ruby, the builtin Random class will perform much better than my compatible Ruby version... It's the goal of Rubinius to minimize the C++ code without a big loss of performance.

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune, while we're here: is JRuby not a good implementation? I could be totally off-base and you'll say, "no it's the worst of all."

Comment: @yar: It is! But the mersenne twister in Ruby will spend most of the time in function calls and very little time doing the basic calculations. By a good implementation, I meant one that could inline those dynamic calls very well (which I don't think the JVM can do). Rubinius aims to do that. I haven't done any performance testing, though, so I'm speculating :-)

Comment: Rubinius, eh? I'll keep my eye on that one, I see it's right in line with what we're talking about. Fascinating in any case... thanks for the chat.

Comment: Shorter version would be 
Random.new.rand(0..100)

Comment: @Juanda: Actually my example is in two lines because it's a terrible idea to call `Random.new` all the time. I've edited my answer

Comment: `Random.rand(10..42)` does not work. The `Random.rand` class method does not accept a range. (Ruby 1.9.2p180)

Comment: @banister: wow, I was convinced that the new api (rand with range, bytes, etc...) was available directly through the Random object. rand with range will be in 1.9.3, and I'll make a feature request for bytes. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 49):

If you're not only seeking for a number but also hex or uuid it's worth mentioning that the `SecureRandom` module found its way from `ActiveSupport` to the ruby core in 1.9.2+. So without the need for a full blown framework:

```
require 'securerandom'

p SecureRandom.random_number(100) #=> 15
p SecureRandom.random_number(100) #=> 88

p SecureRandom.random_number #=> 0.596506046187744
p SecureRandom.random_number #=> 0.350621695741409

p SecureRandom.hex #=> "eb693ec8252cd630102fd0d0fb7c3485"
```

It's documented here: [Ruby 1.9.3 - Module: SecureRandom (lib/securerandom.rb)](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.3/SecureRandom)

Comment: What about if you need 4 digits random number?

Comment: onurozgurozkan I presume `SecureRandom.random_number(1000..9999)`

Comment: `SecureRandom.random_number()` doesn't take a range, so no. You would probably want something like `SecureRandom.random_number(10_000)` (for 0-9999) or `SecureRandom.random_number(9_000)+1_000` (for 1000-9999).

Comment: Random.rand(1000..9999)

Answer (score 39):

You can generate a random number with the `rand` method. The argument passed to the `rand` method should be an `integer` or a `range`, and returns a corresponding random number within the range:

```
rand(9)       # this generates a number between 0 to 8
rand(0 .. 9)  # this generates a number between 0 to 9
rand(1 .. 50) # this generates a number between 1 to 50
#rand(m .. n) # m is the start of the number range, n is the end of number range
```

Comment: I think using your `rand(1..6)` reads clearer than the top answer's `rand(6)+1`.

Answer (score 22):

Well, I figured it out. Apparently there is a builtin (?) function called rand:

```
rand(n + 1)
```

If someone answers with a more detailed answer, I'll mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, it's builtin in the Kernel module.

Answer (score 17):

What about this?

```
n = 3
(0..n).to_a.sample
```

Comment: It should be noted that generating an array of numbers like this solution provides has terrible performance on large ranges as it's O(n) while `rand` is O(1).

Answer (score 15):

Simplest answer to the question:

```
rand(0..n)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use `random_number`.

If a positive integer is given as n, `random_number` returns an integer: 0 <= `random_number` < n.

Use it like this:

```
any_number = SecureRandom.random_number(100)
```

The output will be any number between 0 and 100.

Answer (score 6):

```
rand(6)    #=> gives a random number between 0 and 6 inclusively 
rand(1..6) #=> gives a random number between 1 and 6 inclusively
```

Note that the range option is only available in newer(1.9+ I believe) versions of ruby.

Comment: I believe the range option is only available in `ruby 1.9.3+`.  It didn't work in `1.9.2` when I tried at least.

Answer (score 6):

range = 10..50

**rand(range)**

or

**range.to_a.sample**

or

**range.to_a.shuffle**(this will shuffle whole array and you can pick a random number by first or last or any from this array to pick random one)

Comment: `range.to_a.sample` is an awful idea when the sample is big.

Answer (score 5):

you can do rand(range)

```
x = rand(1..5)
```

Answer (score 4):

This link is going to be helpful regarding this;

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Random.html

**And some more clarity below over the random numbers in ruby;**

Generate an integer from 0 to 10

```
puts (rand() * 10).to_i
```

Generate a number from 0 to 10
In a more readable way

```
puts rand(10)
```

Generate a number from 10 to 15
Including 15

```
puts rand(10..15)
```

**Non-Random Random Numbers**

Generate the same sequence of numbers every time
the program is run

```
srand(5)
```

Generate 10 random numbers

```
puts (0..10).map{rand(0..10)}
```

Comment: Also you can follow this blog for step by step very clear picture over random nos in ruby; http://www.sitepoint.com/tour-random-ruby/

Answer (score 4):

Easy way to get random number in ruby is,

```
def random    
  (1..10).to_a.sample.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it help you. I use this in my app

```
https://github.com/rubyworks/facets
class String

  # Create a random String of given length, using given character set
  #
  # Character set is an Array which can contain Ranges, Arrays, Characters
  #
  # Examples
  #
  #     String.random
  #     => "D9DxFIaqR3dr8Ct1AfmFxHxqGsmA4Oz3"
  #
  #     String.random(10)
  #     => "t8BIna341S"
  #
  #     String.random(10, ['a'..'z'])
  #     => "nstpvixfri"
  #
  #     String.random(10, ['0'..'9'] )
  #     => "0982541042"
  #
  #     String.random(10, ['0'..'9','A'..'F'] )
  #     => "3EBF48AD3D"
  #
  #     BASE64_CHAR_SET =  ["A".."Z", "a".."z", "0".."9", '_', '-']
  #     String.random(10, BASE64_CHAR_SET)
  #     => "xM_1t3qcNn"
  #
  #     SPECIAL_CHARS = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+", "|", "/", "?", ".", ",", ";", ":", "~", "`", "[", "]", "{", "}", "<", ">"]
  #     BASE91_CHAR_SET =  ["A".."Z", "a".."z", "0".."9", SPECIAL_CHARS]
  #     String.random(10, BASE91_CHAR_SET)
  #      => "S(Z]z,J{v;"
  #
  # CREDIT: Tilo Sloboda
  #
  # SEE: https://gist.github.com/tilo/3ee8d94871d30416feba
  #
  # TODO: Move to random.rb in standard library?

  def self.random(len=32, character_set = ["A".."Z", "a".."z", "0".."9"])
    chars = character_set.map{|x| x.is_a?(Range) ? x.to_a : x }.flatten
    Array.new(len){ chars.sample }.join
  end

end
```

https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/5569b03b4c6fd25897444a266ffe25872284be2b/lib/core/facets/string/random.rb

It works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?

```
num = Random.new
num.rand(1..n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to seed the RNG with *srand()* first.

Comment: What happens if you don't call srand()?

Comment: srand is automatically called with the seed being from the current time if it wasn't already called.

Answer (score 1):

Try `array#shuffle` method for randomization

```
array = (1..10).to_a
array.shuffle.first
```

Comment: If you *must* make an entire array, at least replace `.shuffle.first` with `.sample`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby [rand](https://apidock.com/ruby/Random/rand) method for this like below:

```
rand(n+1)
```

You need to use `n+1` as the rand method returns any random number greater than or equal to 0 but less than the passed parameter value.