# Does Ruby Have a Random Number Generator Class?

Tags: ruby, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a random number in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby)

I am just curios but does Ruby have a class for specifically generating random numbers like Java's java.util.Random  class, or is the rand method all Ruby has?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby

Answer (score 2):

There is a rand method in Kernel :)

[API Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/)

```
rand(max=0) => number
Converts max to an integer using max1 = max.to_i.abs. If the result is zero, returns a pseudorandom floating point number greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Otherwise, returns a pseudorandom integer greater than or equal to zero and less than max1. Kernel::srand may be used to ensure repeatable sequences of random numbers between different runs of the program. Ruby currently uses a modified Mersenne Twister with a period of 2**19937-1.

   srand 1234                 #=> 0
   [ rand,  rand ]            #=> [0.191519450163469, 0.49766366626136]
   [ rand(10), rand(1000) ]   #=> [6, 817]
   srand 1234                 #=> 1234
   [ rand,  rand ]            #=> [0.191519450163469, 0.49766366626136]
```