# How to generate a random number between a and b in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, random, range

To generate a random number between 3 and 10, for example, I use: `rand(8) + 3`

Is there a nicer way to do this (something like `rand(3, 10)`) ?

Comment: `def my_rand(x, y); rand(y - x) + x; end`

Comment: @Theo, `y - x + 1`, by the way.

Comment: Try your correct answer on 10 and 10**24 as limits :0 will be very very long awaitng :)

Comment: This works: ```rand(3..10)```

Answer (score 356, accepted):

UPDATE: Ruby 1.9.3 `Kernel#rand` also accepts ranges

```
rand(a..b)
```

http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-3-introduction-and-changes-5428.html

Converting to array may be too expensive, and it's unnecessary.

---

```
(a..b).to_a.sample
```

Or

```
[*a..b].sample
```

---

[Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000756)

*Standard in Ruby 1.8.7+.

Note: was named #choice in 1.8.7 and renamed in later versions.*

But anyway, generating array need resources, and solution you already wrote is the best, you can do.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll stay with the old and the good method :)

Comment: This is a really bad idea, especially if your a and b are of unknown sizes. Try (100000000000000000..100000000000000).to_a.sample and see what I mean : )

Comment: @pixelearth, if you have better idea, which accords the question, you are welcome to post.

Comment: `rand(a..b)` doesn't work, it splits: `TypeError: can't convert Range into Integer`. It's not even supported in [Ruby 2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand)

Comment: @fguillen It works for me in 1.9.3, I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: @anthropomorphic it is working for me in `ruby 2.0.0-p247` so I retract.

Comment: @so_mv this doesn't happen on MRI. (2.0.0p594). `1000000.times{|i| a = rand(1000..9999); puts a if a < 1000}` does not puts a single number

Comment: 1000.times{|i| puts rand(1000-9999)} is wrong. Notice the minus(-) between 1000-9999. It should be 1000..9999. I will remove my comment

Answer (score 88):

```
Random.new.rand(a..b)
```

Where `a` is your lowest value and `b` is your highest value.

Comment: The important difference to note is that if you just call `rand()` you are calling `Kernel#rand`, which only supports a `max` argument. If you want to pass a range, you have to use `Random#rand`, meaning you have to implement this way. +1

Comment: should add that the above applies to 1.9.2

Comment: does it include a and b ?

Answer (score 13):

```
rand(3..10)
```

[Kernel#rand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand)

> When max is a Range, rand returns a random number where range.member?(number) == true.

Answer (score 13):

You can use range operators. Do note the difference between the two forms:

```
3..10  # includes 10
3...10 # doesn't include 10
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead of an answer, but it's also a very important distinction so I gave it an upvote anyway. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
def random_int(min, max)
    rand(max - min) + min
end
```

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby) answer: there is in Ruby 1.9.2, but not in earlier versions. Personally I think rand(8) + 3 is fine, but if you're interested check out the Random class described in the link.

Answer (score 3):

For 10 and 10**24

```
rand(10**24-10)+10
```

Comment: or just `rand(10..10**24)`

Answer (score 3):

And here is a quick benchmark for both `#sample` and `#rand`:

```
irb(main):014:0* Benchmark.bm do |x|
irb(main):015:1*   x.report('sample') { 1_000_000.times { (1..100).to_a.sample } }
irb(main):016:1>   x.report('rand') { 1_000_000.times { rand(1..100) } }
irb(main):017:1> end
       user     system      total        real
sample  3.870000   0.020000   3.890000 (  3.888147)
rand  0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.153557)
```

So, doing `rand(a..b)` is the right thing