# Generate a random number with 7 digits

Tags: ruby

How can I produce a random number in a range from 1 million to 10 million?

`rand(10)` works, I tried `rand(1..10)` and that didn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take your base number, 1,000,000 and add a random number from 0 up to your max - starting number:

```
 1_000_000 + Random.rand(10_000_000 - 1_000_000) #=> 3084592
```

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.8.7, Random doesnt' seem to exist. is it a gem?

Comment: @Blankman: Did you try `require 'random'`, and also checking if it's 1.9.2 only?

Comment: 1.8.7 doesn't have Random. It's in 1.9.2+. Install the backports gem and you'll inherit it in 1.8.7, along with lots of other juicy goodness.

Comment: what are the ramifications of installing backport? (if any)

Comment: Just use `rand`, not `Random.rand`. It works all the way back as far as 1.6.0

Answer (score 6):

It's an instance method:

```
puts Random.new.rand(1_000_000..10_000_000-1)
```

Comment: `1_000_000...10_000_000` is more Ruby-ish.

Answer (score 3):

I find this more readable:

```
7.times.map { rand(1..9) }.join.to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

This will generate a random number between 1,000,000 and 9,999,999.

```
rand(10_000_000-1_000_000)+1_000_000
```

This works in 1.8.7 without any gems(backports, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Or, in case performance is not an issue and you don't want to count zeros:

```
(0...7).map { |i| rand((i == 0 ? 1 : 0)..9) }.join.to_i
```

Comment: Needed a way to avoid zeros

Answer (score 0):

Another option with ruby 1.8.7 compatibility:

> rand(9999999999).to_s.center(10, rand(9).to_s).to_i