# How can generate a random number between 40 and 47 using ruby?

Tags: ruby, random

How can generate a random number between 40 and 47 using ruby?
I tried that but could not understand. [How do I generate a random number in a certain range with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011425/how-do-i-generate-a-random-number-in-a-certain-range-with-ruby)

Comment: This question is really vague. What exactly did you not understand, and equally important, what did you understand or do you think the given solutions do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rand(8)` will generate a random number between 0 and 7 (note that there are indeed 8 numbers in that range).

All you want to do is add 40 to that range, so you'll get numbers between 40 and 47. Like this:

`40 + rand(8)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one `rand(40..47)`

Comment: Note that this will only work with Ruby 1.9 and up.

Comment: i tried it in ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Apologies. I edited my comment.