# Negative random numbers

Tags: ruby, random, generator

I know how to generate numbers with Rails but I don't know how to generate **negative** numbers?

```
prng.rand(1..6) for random of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

[Random doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Random.html) says that you would get an ArgumentError.

Comment: You probably don't want to be calling `Random.new` unless you know the consequences of that. Instead just call `rand` by itself.

Comment: Random.rand(-5..5).
Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby/2773866#2773866

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say you want to generate a number between a and b you can always do that using this formula:

```
randomNum = (b-a)*prng.rand + a
```

So if you want a number between -8 and +7 for example then a=-8 and b=7 and your code would be

```
randomNum = (7-(-8))*prng.rand + (-8)
```

which is equivalent to

```
randomNum=15*prng.rand - 8
```

Comment: randomNum = (7-(-8))*prng.rand(0..1) + (-8)
Wouldn't this generate a with 50% chance ? (when you have 0 with prng.rand(0..1)

Comment: @Awake yes you are correct, use prng.rand instead to generate a random uniform number betwen 0 and 1

Answer (score 7):

Suppose you want to generate negative numbers between -1 to -5

You can simply do this:

```
rand(-5..-1)
```

It will generate random numbers between -5 to -1

Comment: The only rubyesque answer... Maybe add since which ruby version this is possible.

Answer (score 5):

How about you multiply the positive random number by -1

Comment: yes but you will get 100% of negative numbers what i want to do is balance between positive / negative numbers if I do prng.rand(-10..10). But this shouldn't work because of the ArgumentError no ?

Comment: then go 0...10 and subtract 20!

Answer (score 3):

```
def rand(a, b)
  return Random.rand(b - a + 1) + a 
end
rand(-3, 5)
```

Comment: Would not this fail if both a and b are negative?

Comment: Hmm, I just tested with rand(-9, -5) and it seems to work properly yet. Just have to make sure -9 is first as it's the lesser of the two.

Comment: If you do rand (-9, -5) you get Random.rand(-5-(-9)+1)+(-9) = Random.rand(5)-9 ... if rand returns 5 than 5-9=-4 and that is not in the range of (-9, -5)

Comment: Ok, so is there some solution to this problem ?

Comment: Random.rand(5) returns something from 0-4, so it can't return 5 :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to generate a random integer, either 1 or -1 and I used this:

```
prng = Random.new(1)    
prng.rand > 0.5 ? 1 : -1
```