# How to print out a random number between a range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've the following but it doesn't work:

```
<%= (5..30).sample %>
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
<%= [*5..30].sample %>
```

...or...

```
<%= rand(5..30) %>
```

Comment: The first solution is inefficient. Good thing it's not a random number between 5 and a million... The second solution works only in Ruby 1.9.3. This question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby

Comment: @Marc-AndréLaortune: Yeah, I agree, on all things. I'll throw in my close vote.

Comment: Rand is much more efficient

Answer (score 6):

This would generate a random number in that range:

```
5 + rand(25)
```

Simply add the min to the rand(max-min).

Answer (score 6):

`Range` has no `#sample` method. Use the one from `Array` instead.

```
<%= (5..30).to_a.sample %>
```

Answer (score 3):

for 1 random number:

```
a = (5...30).sort_by{rand}[1]
# => 7
```

It seems more verbose than what others have suggested, but from here, it's easy to pick three random unique numbers from the same range:

```
a = (5...30).sort_by{rand}[1..3]
# => [19, 22, 28]
```

Or 20:

```
a = (5...30).sort_by{rand}[1..20]
# => [7, 12, 16, 14, 13, 15, 22, 17, 24, 19, 20, 10, 21, 26, 29, 9, 23, 27, 8, 18]
```

Might come in useful for someone who needs to display 5 random foos in their sidebar

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Marc-Andre Lafortune, I discovered that the following is much better:

```
a=[*5..30].sample(3)
```

Comment: Terribly inefficient! Your solution is O(n log n) instead of a solution in O(1)! Use `Array#sample` if you need many random samples from an array.

Comment: thanks @Marc-Andre, you learn something new everyday. I updated my answer with something based on your suggestion