# How to randomly pick either 4 or 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

With ruby on rails, ruby, how can I randomly select either 4 or 5?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a random number in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby)

Comment: I understand closing this as a duplicate, but why the downvotes? It's clearly worded, on topic, and something that would not be obvious to a new Ruby programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
four_or_five = rand(2) == 0 ? 4 : 5
```

Since rand(num) chooses a value between 0 and `num`, non-inclusive, there's a 50% chance of 0 being chosen.  Thus, `four_or_five` will be 4 or 5 with equal probability.

Answer (score 5):

Just use Ruby's rand function:

```
4+rand(2)
=> 4
4+rand(2)
=> 5
4+rand(2)
=> 5
```

Answer (score 5):

I like a nice simple one liner.

```
(4..5).to_a.sample
```

Comment: Why overcomplicating? `[4, 5].sample`

Comment: +1 for using `Array#sample`. However, no need to create a Range. Simply use `%w( 4 5 ).sample`.

Comment: Ha that's true, Sergio. I just usually go straight to ranges because usually it's between larger numbers (like `(1..100)`) but yeah in this case that be easier.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti: that would be array of strings. Not cool.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're right, but it depends on what you need to do. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.9.3 I think you can just do:

```
rand(4..5)
```