# How to draw from exponential distribution in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, statistics, random

In Ruby, I need to draw from an exponential distribution with mean `m`. Please show me how to do it quickly and efficiently. Eg. let's have:

```
m = 4.2

def exponential_distribution
  rand( m * 2 )
end
```

But of course, this code is wrong, and also, it only returns whole number results. I'm already tired today, please hint me towards a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [the `distribution` gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/distribution)? Here's an example:

```
require 'distribution'

mean = 4.2
lambda = mean**-1

# generate a rng with exponential distribution
rng = Distribution::Exponential.rng(lambda)

# sample a value
sample = rng.call
```

If you need to change the value of `lambda` very often it might be useful to use the `p_value` method directly. A good sample can be found in [the source code for `Distribution::Exponential#rng`](https://github.com/clbustos/distribution/blob/master/lib/distribution/exponential/ruby.rb#L7), which basically just uses `p_value` internally. Here's an example of how to do it:

```
require 'distribution'

# use the same rng for each call
rng = Random

1.step(5, 0.1) do |mean|
  lambda = mean**-1

  # sample a value
  sample = Distribution::Exponential.p_value(rng.rand, lambda)
end
```

Comment: How many such gems are there? How about the comparison between using eg. Ruby frontend to R? Once I'm sure I've a good one, I'll hapilly use it. Basically this was what I wanted.

Comment: I believe it is made and used by the guys from SciRuby and i've had a great experience with that. I do not know about any competiting gems.

Comment: Oh really :-) I'm on my way to become one of those guys, so good to know :-)

Comment: Please could you help me with one more thing: My lambda changes very often, could you show me how to do it withoug creating a Proc object?

Comment: Ok i added the code. Basically the exponential distribution RNG takes one parameter lambda. Since the mean of the exponential distribution is `m = λ^-1` you want to pass `λ = m^-1` as argument (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

Comment: Thanks, but, the last thing, can I do it without creating a Proc? Proc is amazing for when you draw from the same distribution many times. But if you only draw once, creating Proc is perhaps too much? (I've already accepted the answer.)

Comment: You're welcome! Btw have a look into [this answer by Marc-André Lafortune](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby/2773866#2773866) (see Notes on `Random.new`) to see why it is a good idea to use the same RNG again, anyway!

Comment: @p11y would you mind explaining this line of code 1.step(5, 0.1) do |mean|

Comment: @Beast_Code it means count from 1 to 5 in steps of 0.1. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Numeric.html#method-i-step

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it from scratch you can use [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

```
def exponential(mean)
  -mean * Math.log(rand) if mean > 0
end
```

If you want to parameterize it with rate `lambda`, the mean and rate are inverses of each other.  Divide by `-lambda` rather than multiplying by `-mean`.

Technically it should be `log(1.0 - rand)`, but since `1.0 - rand` has a uniform distribution you can save one arithmetic operation by just using `rand`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really too tired today.