# Google search of: "rand between -1 and 1 ruby" gives 0 results

Tags: google-search

When I search Google to give me different methods to generate a random number between -1 and 1 using:

**rand between -1 and 1 ruby**

it gives me did not find any documents. Anyone know why? Seems like a basic search query to me.

Comment: try: rand between "-1" and "1" ruby. minus sigh in googe query basically excludes following word/statement from search results. so you are excluding "1"

Comment: this really belongs on webapps or superuser, it's not a programming problem.

Comment: [Here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/how-to-use-google-pro-tips-tricks/) is something useful to get you started using Google Search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minus sign operator in a Google search is saying "exclude", so you're saying "exclude 1 and include 1", so zero results.

> Similarly, if you want to exclude a word entirely, you can add a dash
>   before it—like `justin bieber -sucks` if you want sites that only speak
>   of Justin Bieber in a positive light.

-[LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/top-10-clever-google-search-tricks-1450186165)

As to the question you're searching for, check this out...
-[How to get a random number in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby)