# Return true with weight probability in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math

I want a Ruby method to return `true` based on a percent probability.

```
def random_true(probability)
    # Math to randomly return true based on weighted probability 
end
```

Then I could just call `random_true(0.4)` (implying 40% chance of it returning `true`).

Would also be fine if it was a simple one-liner that didn't even need a method.

i.e. `return true if XYZ`

Comment: `rand <= probability` (or `probability <= rand`) is all you need. See [Kernel#rand](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand). That is, `rand` generates a pseudo-random number between zero and one, so `rand <= probability` returns `true` or `false`. Incidentally, where you say "percent probability" I think you mean just "probability", as probabilites are numbers (not percents) between zero and one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you gave this same answer in a question I asked a while ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585659/coin-flipper-with-n-probability-of-heads